# Is there any way to embed egrep and wget in my application?

Tags: c++, wget, grep

i need in my application the feathers that the good old egrep and wget give me , but i can't execute them as 
separate process i need them as embedded functions in my application 
is there any way to do that ? cross platform and c++

Comment: Why can't you execute them as separate processes?

Answer (score 2):

For getting `wget` functionality you could use [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expressions library. [Boost::Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) is a common option. A less portable option for now is the [Visual C++ Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=D466226B-8DAB-445F-A7B4-448B326C48E7&displaylang=en) or the [Dikumware](http://www.dinkumware.com/tr1.aspx) TR1 implementations, which already come with regular expressions support. Finally you can search google for "C++ regular expressions" and you should be offered with other options.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from this mailing list entry, wget is probably not available in library form currently:

http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-wget@gnu.org/msg00431.html