# My Current Project Needs to Snapshot a website

Tags: c++, c

My Current Project Needs to Snapshot a website, the whole website and a thumbnail, with an inputed url.

How can i get it done in C, C++?

Comment: You should try to get started on your own and then post specific questions if you get stuck or have problems.  No one is going to design your project for you.

Comment: -1 because this a very unspecific question. If you had done the smallest amount of research yourself first, you would be able to ask a more specific question and thus receive more helpful answers.

Answer (score 2):

Try [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221650/is-there-any-way-to-embed-egrep-and-wget-in-my-application)

Depending on your O/S you could also launch wget using [execv](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_execv.htm) or [execv_](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/886kc0as%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). [boost.process](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/) offers cross-platform ways to do this but is not (yet) an official part of boost.